# Are questions tagged with one of my Watched Tags no longer highlighted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I watch the tags `minecraft-java-edition` and `minecraft-commands`, which makes them highlighted in the Top Questions feed. Recently, these questions stopped being highlighted.

Are questions tagged with one of my Watched Tags no longer highlighted? If so, why? I think this was a very useful feature.

Comment: It looks like this is happening on all of the sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [a post on the StackExchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366321/ignored-and-watched-tags-seem-broken), the feature was temporarily broken.

They have since implemented a fix. I can confirm that both watched tags and ignored tags have resumed working as intended.